# Need assistance with a jQuery plugin - TextExt input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, jquery-textext

I'm using a plugin from: http://textextjs.com/

This is the summary of my code:

```
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
agoras = $('#tags').val();
alert(agoras);
</script>

<input type="text" id="tags" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tags').textext({
plugins : 'autocomplete filter tags',
tagsItems : [ 'Basic', 'Javascript', 'PHP', 'Scala' ]
});
</script>

</body>
```

The tags work great. My only problem is that I can't seem to get the input. It always just alerts a blank string. I tried looking at the docs but I just can't find the command that will get the input from the text box. Any ideas?

P.S. I already tried changing the arrangement of the script tags. No other arrangement still makes it work. I really think there's a js function to get the input content.

Comment: use alert below the input tag.....

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: try `alert( $('#tags').textext()[0] )`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'input'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally... I was able to find the code to get the value. It's as simple as this:

```
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
agoras = $('#tags').textext()[0].hiddenInput().val();
alert(agoras);
</script>

<input type="text" id="tags" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tags').textext({
plugins : 'autocomplete filter tags',
tagsItems : [ 'Basic', 'Javascript', 'PHP', 'Scala' ]
});
</script>

</body>
```

Specifically, all I needed to do was this:

```
agoras = $('#tags').textext()[0].hiddenInput().val();
```

Comment: Where'd you find about hiddenInput? I couldn't find it anywhere in textextjs.com

Comment: Their docs are lacking quite a lot, and you'll need to dig deep into the source code to figure out some stuff.